# Change Divider color in Android PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

Anyone know how to change divider color in Android PreferenceActivity ?

Answer (score 5):

```
PreferenceActivity.getListView().setDivider(Drawable divider);
```

Where divider is a drawable that can be a `shape`, `color`, `gradient`, `image` (png etc).